# Python 3 if/elif/else operator always goes to else

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm writing a discord bot using Python 3.5 and i've run into an issue and I can't seem to solve it, here is the code

```
if message.content.startswith('!juvialist'):
    decision = message.content[10:]
    if decision == 'add':
        await client.send_message(message.channel, 'Added')
    elif decision == 'remove':
        await client.send_message(message.channel, 'Removed')
    else:
        await client.send_message(message.channel, decision + ' is an invalid parameter')
```

basically, what happens here is if the user types '!juvialist add' python slices everything before add and puts into a string called decision, then an IF statement decides what happens, if it's an add or remove it does something, else it tells the user that the parameter is wrong, but the problem is, even if it's correct, it always goes to else and returns an error

Error:

[image]

I've tried doing the same thing but in slightly different ways based on Google searches, looking at Python documentation on IF statements isn't much help either, which probably means that i'm missing something ridiculously obvious, so i'd appreciate it if you could help me here, thank you.

Comment: If you print decision what is the output

Comment: Seems that doing `message.content[10:]` would include a leading space, giving ` add` rather than the expected `add`. You can either start from 11, or trim your strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you missed up `space`. In fact your `decision` is `" add"` or whatever.

Put `decision = message.content[11:]` instead.

Or even better idea would be `decision = message.content[10:].strip()`

Comment: Even better would be `decision = message.content.split()[1]`, decoupling this conditional from the prefix length.

Answer (score -1):

Even better is to use `in` instead of `==`:

```
if message.content.startswith('!juvialist'):
    if ' add ' in message.content:
        await client.send_message(message.channel, 'Added')
    elif ' remove ' in message.content:
        await client.send_message(message.channel, 'Removed')
    else:
        # etc.
```

Comment: This aproach can lead to potential problems, if user has several commands and their names somehow intersect, e.g. 'add' and 'addgroup'. 'add' in 'addgroup' == True.

Comment: This doesn't fix the problem itself. What if message.content ends with command? I mean after 'add' we have \n ?

Comment: This also ignores the order: `!juvialist hello add lel` would be ok here but not in the code suggested by the question.

Comment: @grapes think of the context, add is a verb, you wouldn't be putting it at the **end** of a command, ditto for remove.

Comment: Mate, this aproach doesnt work, anyway. What about 'apply' commands and others, who can finish the command line? What if `add` will appear in the parematers not at the first position? Command interpreters are NOT using such aproach as `command_line.find(' command '')', this design leads to future errors.